# Insert ActionLink into existing tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a default internet application template from MVC4 and I would like to add some links to the `<nav>` tag depending on the user logged in.

I.e all the users have a default navigation panel, but if it is an admin logged in, he should have extra link for Managing product stock.

Right now it looks like that(from _Layout.cshtml):

```
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Browse", "Product")</li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

And I need somehow insert new ActionLink. I've tried to make an `if` statement inside the default layout, but it does not work. How could I add an extra `<li>` tag inside this `<nav>`? I am not familiar with JavaScript or JQuery, but can it be done using MVC features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved using the razor syntax

```
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Browse", "Product")</li>
                    @if( User.IsInRole("Admin") ){
                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "...", "...")</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>
```